# Emulating clicks into PopMenu windows

Tags: c, winapi, window

I'm coding a software which is responsible for emulating clicks in other process and I've managed to do it with PostMessage(), but there is an interesting thing:

First, the popupmenu is not a child from the window i can emulate clicks successfully, it looks like it is a child from the Desktop window (#32769 class).

I'm able to get a handle of the popupmenu(#32868 class) but when I send a PostMessage with WM_LBUTTONDOWN the window seems to handle the message but i don`t really know what happens because spy++ somehow is unable to get window messages from this window.

Can someone tell me why spy++ does not get it's messages, and if there is any way to emulate a mouseclick into this misterious popupmenu window?

Comment: Use Automation. That's what it's for.

Comment: hey reymond, what do you mean with automation?

Comment: @user3368568: he is referring to [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff486375.aspx), an API for programmably accessing and manipulating UI elements, especially over process boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

Try [mouse_event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646260%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function in user32.dll:

```
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, X, Y, 0, 0);
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, X, Y, 0, 0);
```

Comment: hello mustafa, both mouse_event and sendinput don`t work because the window can be created in diferent positions depending of current cursor position, i`d like to solve the problem sending a window message to it`s handler